# Removing a folder called ~

Tags: bash, rm

I had bug in my bash script that created folder called

```
~
```

Anyway that lead me to another problem which is exscuting the following command:

```
rm -fr ~
```

ooopsss removed my home folder...

so my question is:

why rm works on the alias and not on the actual folder that is listed where I am?

You can reproduce it, by the following:

```
cd /tmp/
mkdir "~"
which rm ~
```

now you will see that the output of which rm ~ 
is pointing to the actual home folder and not the the ~ which was created in tmp

Comment: Did you try to quote it with single quotes?

Comment: From now I will start using quotes when pointing to path or adding ./ glad it happened, I truly believe that some of the biggest mistakes are the biggest lessons, and I am glad to have backup :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `~` is expanded by the shell to the home directory name *before* `rm` is called, the `rm` program is unaware of it.

Expansion of magic characters like this can be suppressed by enclosing them in quotes:

```
$ echo ~
/Users/fredbloggs
$ echo '~'
~
```

Comment: so rm / any other sh command with quotes '~' will make bash to use the actual string and it will disregard the alias?

Comment: Yes, but calling `~` an alias is not accurate since an alias is a specific shell construct.  This is called *Tilde Expansion*, search for that in `man bash`.

Answer (score 4):

```
rm -R ./~
```

That will make it look for ~ in the current directory. If you run

```
rm -rf ~
```

You are removing the original ~ so you need to indirect with `./~`

This happens because of the expansion of the special character

Comment: So adding the ./ to ~ will caused bash to disregard the ~ alias because it is different string now

Comment: Exactly. If you want to use ~ you can use it in quotes as the other answer explained, that way the shell wont expand the special character